# Prevent selection of neighbouring div using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code -

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body answer">
   Some text content
   <br/>
</div>
<div class="panel-body edit-area">
<div class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 20px">
   <div class="panel-data" style="margin-bottom:10px; display: none">
      <div class='input-group'>
         <input type='text' class='submit-edit-request' placeholder='Type content & hit enter' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="separator">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Request Edit</button>
   </div>
</div></div></div>
```

The problem is that whenever I try to double click and select the text content in the 'answer' div, the text contained in the button is also getting selected. I have tried adding -webkit-user-select attribute to the button and set it as none but it doesn't help.

Comment: use `aria-hidden` for `button` that might be helpful !!

Comment: doesn't seem to work!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khpoyqgm/1/).

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding an <hr> tag after the text